# Add watermark to ffmpeg MP4 encoding process in Windows?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, encoding, watermark

Want to apologize off the bat as I am by no means familiar with working with ffmpeg and after trying countless times unsuccessfully to accomplish adding a PNG image watermark to my videos I'm hoping that someone might be able to lend some help my way.

I understand that ffmpeg is a Linux based application, however I am hoping to accomplish this within Windows 7 64-bit.

I am using what I've been told is an extremely outdated preset, however it fits my needs and I am a creature of habit when it comes to my encoding practices.

Below are what I hope to accomplish:

1. Batch encode FLV to MP4 retaining the original file name.
2. Watermark all video files with a PNG image in the lower right hand corner of the video.
3. Auto-split files at a designated cut-off time and keeping the original file name and just adding something like -00, -01, etc. to the end of the file name.

Below is the preset that I currently use.  In the GUI I usually stick with a 15/16 for the CRF, which gives me an overall output of about 56% of the original file size.

```
coder=1
flags=+loop
cmp=+chroma
partitions=-parti8x8-parti4x4-partp8x8-partb8x8
me_method=dia
subq=2
me_range=16
g=250
keyint_min=25
sc_threshold=40
i_qfactor=0.71
b_strategy=2
qcomp=0.6
qmin=10
qmax=51
qdiff=4
bf=3
refs=1
directpred=3
trellis=0
flags2=+bpyramid-mixed_refs+wpred-dct8x8+fastpskip
wpredp=2
rc_lookahead=50
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, and again I apologize for my ignorance due to not having any technical background when it comes to coding.

Comment: There are already threads which discuss watermarking in Stack Exchange. Do a search and after that if it does not solve your problem, post your question with specific command used by you and the console output of ffmpeg command. For starters see [this](http://superuser.com/search?q=ffmpeg+watermark). Also, for different objectives such as cutting off at a particular duration, you are better off asking separate questions.

Answer (score 3):

### Some recommendations

> I understand that ffmpeg is a Linux based application, however I am hoping to accomplish this within Windows 7 64-bit.

`ffmpeg` is available for Windows, OS X, Linux, and other platforms. See the [FFmpeg download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for several options.

Your first step should be to download a recent build of `ffmpeg`. It is recommended to regularly get a new build since [FFmpeg development is very active](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=shortlog) and to take advantage of fixed bugs. Daily builds for Windows are available at [Zeranoe FFmpeg Builds](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/).

> I am using what I've been told is an extremely outdated preset, however it fits my needs and I am a creature of habit when it comes to my encoding practices.

There is no reason for you to use an old, unsupported preset that may use old, unsupported options. Just use `-preset veryfast` instead: it's basically very similar to your old, unsupported preset. `ffmpeg` no longer uses the text file type of "emulating" presets for x264 but now accesses them directly.

### Adding a watermark

[image: Nahanni]

Use the [`overlay` video filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay):

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -i logo.png -filter_complex \
"[0:v][1:v]overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10[watermark]" -map "[watermark]" \
-map 0:a -codec:v libx264 -preset veryfast -crf 18 -codec:a copy \
output.mp4
```

- The filtergraph: `[0:v][1:v]overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10[watermark]`

  - `[0:v]` is a stream specifier referring to the video stream(s) of the first input (`input.flv`). `[1:v]` refers to the video stream(s) of the second input (`logo.png`).
  - `W-w-10` is placing the *x* axis and refers to the width of the main input (`W`) and the width of the overlay input (`w`). `H-h-10` is similar but for the *y* axis. This example places the logo in the bottom right with a padding of 10 pixels. See [`overlay` video filter documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) for more info.
  - `[watermark]` is the output link label. Some omit this but I prefer to explicitly label my outputs to remove ambiguity.
- `-crf 18` is often considered roughly "visually lossless", so I assume that value will suffice for you. If not then reduce the value until you achieve an acceptable quality. Then use the slowest preset you have patience for. See the [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) for more info on `-crf` and `-preset`.
- `-codec:a copy` will [stream copy](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) the audio. If you player does not like what I assume is MP3 audio then use something like `-codec:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 128k` instead. See the [FFmpeg and AAC Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AACEncodingGuide) for more info.

### Segmenting the video

Use the [`segment` muxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment):

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -i logo.png -filter_complex \
"[0:v][1:v]overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10[watermark]" -map "[watermark]" \
-map 0:a -codec:v libx264 -preset veryfast -crf 18 -codec:a copy \
-f segment -segment_time 20 -segment_list out.csv output.mp4
```

Segments will be approximately 20 seconds in duration and outputs will be named `output-000.mp4`, `output-001.mp4`, `output-002.mp4`, etc. See the [`segment` muxer documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) for more detailed information and examples.

### Batch encoding

#### Linux

Using a Bash "for loop":

```
$ mkdir outputdir
$ for file in *.flv; do ffmpeg -i "$file" -i logo.png -filter_complex \
"[0:v][1:v]overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10[watermark]" -map "[watermark]" \
-map 0:a -codec:v libx264 -preset veryfast -crf 18 -codec:a copy \
-f segment -segment_time 20 -segment_list outputdir/out.csv \
outputdir/"${file%.flv}-%03d.mp4"; done
```

#### Windows

```
for %%a in ("*.flv") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10[watermark]" -map "[watermark]" -map 0:a -codec:v libx264 -preset veryfast -crf 18 -codec:a copy -f segment -segment_time 20 -segment_list "outputfolder\out.csv" "outputfolder\%%~na-%%03d.mp4"
pause
```

You can dump this into a text editor and name it `watermark.bat` and then doubleclick it to execute. In Windows Explorer you will probably have to show hidden system files for `watermark.bat` to show up.